# Rotate ytick after rotating polaraxis

Tags: rotating, polarplot

I rotated a polaraxis 90 degree CCW.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots} %Plots direkt in LaTeX aus externen Dateien berechnen
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest} % Use the latest settings, so we don't get trapped with old bugs or limited features.
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar} %für polare Plots
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar} %für polare Plots

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}         
    \begin{polaraxis}[
        y dir=reverse, 
        rotate=90,  
        xticklabel style={anchor=-\tick-90}, 
        xtick={0,30,...,330},
        y coord trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1+60},   
        y coord inv trafo/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-60},
        ytick={-60,-40,-20,0,20,40,60},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (90,1) (180,1) (270,1)} --cycle;
    \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want rotate the ytick's back 90 degree CW so the numbers are under the dark line at the 90 degree position.

I tried xmin=90,xmax=450. Than the numbers and line is at the right position, but my outer degree-numbers are not right. The degree-numbers should be 0°-330°.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you complete the code to a minimal compilable example, mentioning the needed TikZ libraries?

Comment: I edit the first post.

Comment: anyone with a new idea on my edit in the first post?